# Acessing objects in Session scope

Tags: jsp, session-variables

I am building a UI template & hence no java files. However I need java objects , so I have class definition in my jsp only.I need to print gameState property of each object in "results" array. How to print it ?

There is something wrong with this line " ${sessionScope['results'][innerItemNumber].gameState}[br]". I am not sure of the syntax.

I get an error "javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'gameState' not readable on type java.lang.String ".

test.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<% 
    class Result {
        String gameState;
        String result;
        String optional;

        public Result(String gameState, String result, String optional) {
            this.gameState = gameState;
            this.result = result;
            this.optional = optional;
        }....
        .....// Getters & setters 
 }
%>

<%  java.util.ArrayList<Result> results = new java.util.ArrayList<Result>();
    results.add(new Result("Kick off", "14:00", ""));
    results.add(new Result("1st Half", "2-2", ""));
    results.add(new Result("1st Half", "2-1", ""));
    results.add(new Result("Peanalties", "3-6", "(1-1 FT)"));
    results.add(new Result("2nd Half", "2-0", ""));     
 %>
....
.....
<c:forEach items="0,1,2,3,4,5,6" var="innerItemNumber">  
<cell class="vertical-align-middle" width="33%" text-align="center">

        ${sessionScope['results'][innerItemNumber].gameState}[br]  ?????????

</cell>
</c:forEach >
```

Comment: Hope you need to call something like `${sessionScope.results}` or `<% session.getAttribute("results"); %>`

Comment: I need to access the property of results.Something like ${sessionScope.results.gameState}. What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: If your 'results' is a list.. you can access like ${sessionScope.results.get(i).gameState}, just like how you operate on a list. Look at the container generated code of your JSP for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Move your class out of jsp in some of your packages and everithing will work. Don't foget make it public.